# Variable Name out of Two Concatenated Strings

Tags: c++

Let's assume we've got some buttons, which may be named as follows:

```
toggleBtn_A;
toggleBtn_B;
toggleBtn_C;
```

We've also got a string that we search through:

```
std::string stringToSearch = "ABCD";
```

Now we want to make the following code work:

```
    std::string::size_type found = stringToSearch.find('B'); // found the 'B' position

    if (found != std::string::npos) {
        // if it's 'B' then it could be the letter following 'B', i.e. 'C' (or some other logical condition)
        // toggleBtn_C->DoSomething();

        // which can also be represented as follows:
        // toggleBtn_'stringToSearch[found + n]'->DoSomething();
    }
```

Would you be so kind as to tell me whether there's a simple way of implementing this? Of concatenating two strings resulting in a defined variable of which at least one should probably be calculated dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible, because variable names only exist at compile-time, not at runtime. `std::map` might be useful.

Comment: No there is not.   It might be possible to set up some sort of map between a letter (`'B`) and a pointer to an object (e.g. `toggleBtn_B`).   A standard associative container which can be used for that would be `std::map<char, Button *>`  (if every character maps to exactly one button, otherwise another container from the standard library is needed).   But it is necessary to write code explicitly to initialise the map before attempting to use it - the compiler won't implicitly do that for you.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could try a switch:

```
switch(letter)
{
    case "A":           
            toggleBtn_B->DoSomething();
            break;
    case "B":           
            toggleBtn_C->DoSomething();
            break;
    case "C":           
            toggleBtn_->DoSomething();
            break;
    case "D":  
            toggleBtn_A->DoSomething();
            break;
    default:
            //whatever you wish
}
```

Comment: You probably meant to use single quotes there...?